# R Replacing NA values with the next value of another column value within groups

Tags: r, data.table, dplyr

I have a dataframe as below

```
tmpdf <- data.frame(spaceNum=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,2), time.IN=c("2015-09-04 16:30", "2015-09-04 19:50", "2015-09-04 21:00", "2015-09-05 12:00", "2015 09-05 13:00", "2015 09-05 16:00", "2015 09-05 17:00"), time.OUT= c("2015-09-04 18:00", "NA", "NA","NA", "2015-09-05 13:21", "2015 09-05 16:48", "NA"))

> tmpdf
  spaceNum          time.IN         time.OUT
1        1 2015-09-04 16:30 2015-09-04 18:00
2        1 2015-09-04 19:50               NA
3        1 2015-09-04 21:00               NA
4        2 2015-09-05 12:00               NA
5        2 2015 09-05 13:00 2015-09-05 13:21
6        2 2015 09-05 16:00 2015 09-05 16:48
7        2 2015 09-05 17:00               NA
>
```

I want to replace the NA value of `time.OUT` to the next rows value of `time.IN` which is not NULL and within the same `spaceNum` group. ie, Below are my expect results.

```
 spaceNum          time.IN         time.OUT
    1        1 2015-09-04 16:30 2015-09-04 18:00
    2        1 2015-09-04 19:50 2015-09-04 21:00
    3        1 2015-09-04 21:00               NA
    4        2 2015-09-05 12:00 2015-09-05 13:00
    5        2 2015 09-05 13:00 2015-09-05 13:21
    6        2 2015 09-05 16:00 2015 09-05 16:48
    7        2 2015 09-05 17:00               NA
```

It seem dplyr  or data.table can do this, and I have search previous questions but doesn't find proper way to this yet.

This may simple questions for expert R user, but for me, it head me up couple hours already and did't find good solution.  Please help me!! Thanks.

Comment: You havn't provided an example when `time.IN` is NULL and how it should be handled

Comment: Are the columns in your real data also of class `factor` as in your example data?

Comment: @David, to  simplify the questions, I am thinking  just keep time.OUT as NULL  if the next row value of time.IN is NULL.

Comment: @docendo, the real data of time.IN and time.OUT should be in POSIXct format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's is a possible `dplyr` solution. This is a combination of `ifelse` and `lead`, while the end product should be converted to `as.POSIXct` again as a result of lost information due to the use of `ifelse`

```
library(dplyr)
tmpdf %>%
  group_by(spaceNum) %>%
  mutate(time.OUT = as.POSIXct(ifelse(is.na(time.OUT), lead(time.IN), time.OUT), origin = "1970-01-01"))
# Source: local data frame [7 x 3]
# Groups: spaceNum
# 
#   spaceNum             time.IN            time.OUT
# 1        1 2015-09-04 16:30:00 2015-09-04 18:00:00
# 2        1 2015-09-04 19:50:00 2015-09-04 21:00:00
# 3        1 2015-09-04 21:00:00                <NA>
# 4        2 2015-09-05 12:00:00 2015-09-05 13:00:00
# 5        2 2015-09-05 13:00:00 2015-09-05 13:21:00
# 6        2 2015-09-05 16:00:00 2015-09-05 16:48:00
# 7        2 2015-09-05 17:00:00                <NA>
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `data.table` to do this.  We convert the `factor` 'time' columns to `character` class after converting the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(tmpdf)`).  Here, I assumed that `NA`s are real `NA` instead of the character strings.  Grouped by 'spaceNum', we create a new column 'v1' using the `shift` from the devel version of data.table. Assign the 'time.OUT' values to 'v1' corresponding to the `NA` elements in 'time.out'.  We can also assign the unwanted columns to 'NULL', i.e. 'v1'

```
library(data.table)#v1.9.5+
setDT(tmpdf)[, (2:3) :=lapply(.SD, as.character), .SDcols=2:3]
tmpdf[, v1:=shift(time.IN, type='lead'), spaceNum][is.na(time.OUT), 
                   time.OUT:= v1][, v1:= NULL]
tmpdf
#   spaceNum          time.IN         time.OUT
#1:        1 2015-09-04 16:30 2015-09-04 18:00
#2:        1 2015-09-04 19:50 2015-09-04 21:00
#3:        1 2015-09-04 21:00               NA
#4:        2 2015-09-05 12:00 2015 09-05 13:00
#5:        2 2015 09-05 13:00 2015-09-05 13:21
#6:        2 2015 09-05 16:00 2015 09-05 16:48
#7:        2 2015 09-05 17:00               NA
```

Noticed that in the example dataset, in addition to the character `"NA"`, we have also multiple formats for the 'time' columns. i.e. `2015 09-05 16:48` and `2015-09-05 13:21`.  If we need to convert to `POSIXct`, we can use `library(lubridate)` as it can take multiple formats.

```
library(lubridate)
tmpdf[, (2:3) := lapply(.SD, ymd_hm), .SDcols=2:3]
tmpdf
#  spaceNum             time.IN            time.OUT
#1:        1 2015-09-04 16:30:00 2015-09-04 18:00:00
#2:        1 2015-09-04 19:50:00 2015-09-04 21:00:00
#3:        1 2015-09-04 21:00:00                <NA>
#4:        2 2015-09-05 12:00:00 2015-09-05 13:00:00
#5:        2 2015-09-05 13:00:00 2015-09-05 13:21:00
#6:        2 2015-09-05 16:00:00 2015-09-05 16:48:00
#7:        2 2015-09-05 17:00:00                <NA>
```

Comment: Thanks akrun for the data.table solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

First of all build df with character vectors not factors.
Then put all NA values in `sapply`.
The function in `sapply` finds where next time.IN after NA that happens same day. And pull them from original df. At last assign them into df's NA values.

```
tmpdf <- data.frame(spaceNum=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,2), 
time.IN=c("2015-09-04 16:30", "2015-09-04 19:50", "2015-09-04 21:00", "2015-09-05 12:00", "2015 09-05 13:00", "2015 09-05 16:00", "2015 09-05 17:00"), 
time.OUT= c("2015-09-04 18:00", NA, NA,NA, "2015-09-05 13:21", "2015 09-05 16:48", NA),stringsAsFactors = F)

tmp<-tmpdf[unlist(
             sapply(which(is.na(tmpdf[,3])),function(x){
               if(tmpdf[x,1]==tmpdf[x+1,1] && !is.na(tmpdf[x,1]==tmpdf[x+1,1])) x+1 
               else NA
               })), 2]

tmpdf[which(is.na(tmpdf[,3])),3]<-tmp

> tmpdf
  spaceNum          time.IN         time.OUT
1        1 2015-09-04 16:30 2015-09-04 18:00
2        1 2015-09-04 19:50 2015-09-04 21:00
3        1 2015-09-04 21:00             <NA>
4        2 2015-09-05 12:00 2015 09-05 13:00
5        2 2015 09-05 13:00 2015-09-05 13:21
6        2 2015 09-05 16:00 2015 09-05 16:48
7        2 2015 09-05 17:00             <NA>
```

Comment: @Tensibai I am writing some explanations. Thank you btw.

Comment: @vck, also thanks for your sol with sapply, BTW, it seem it have a tydo, tmpdf[which(is.na(tmpdf[,3])),3]<-kamil,   "kamil" should be "tmp", right?

Comment: @vck I edited for some formatting, feel free to rollback if you don't find it useful